# Is there a way to Ignore escape characters but still use string interpolation? C#

Tags: c#

So, the string I need to implement is this, I am using .Net 4.5.2 in c# in visual studio 2019, I want the espected output to be exactly as below albeit with FIRSTNAME being replaced by a variable.

```
beneficiaryFirstName: \\\"FIRSTNAME\\\"
```

This is being used with a lot of similarly structured strings to join them together to form a large graphQL query.  The problem I have is that VStudio keeps throwing up errors.

Edit : I would like to make clear, I need the \'s in the string result, and I need FIRSTNAME to be treated as a variable.

I have attempted to use this.

```
$@"beneficiaryFirstName: \\\"{{FIRSTNAME}}\\\""
```

But get told that it there's unexpected characters "" and "".

What is the best way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the right escaping

```
var FIRSTNAME = "Bob";

var pad = @"\\\";

var test1 = $"beneficiaryFirstName: \\\\\\\"{FIRSTNAME}\\\\\\\"";
var test2 = @$"beneficiaryFirstName: \\\""{FIRSTNAME}\\\""";
var test3 = $"beneficiaryFirstName: {pad}\"{FIRSTNAME}{pad}\"";

Console.WriteLine(test1);
Console.WriteLine(test2);
Console.WriteLine(test3);
```

**Output**

```
beneficiaryFirstName: \\\"Bob\\\"
beneficiaryFirstName: \\\"Bob\\\"
beneficiaryFirstName: \\\"Bob\\\"
```

<sub>***Disclaimer**, I am not sure if the quotes are correct in your example, they seem like they are in weird places, though that could be just how it is*</sub>

Comment: @MatthewWatson ahh yes thanks

Comment: Thank you, perfection. Went with the @$ result but the top one worked too. Have a great day General!

Comment: @CallumSmith I'm not saying you should mark this answer correct, however the idea is when you have your solution, you smash the green tick.

Comment: Apologies, ticked now, yes essentially these are all being joined together for a large graphQL query, your answer did provide what I needed however. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.

```
string FIRSTNAME = "YourName";
string temp = $"beneficiaryFirstName: {FIRSTNAME}";
Console.WriteLine(temp);
```

It will print

> beneficiaryFirstName: YourName

You can try this `string temp = $"beneficiaryFirstName: \\\\{FIRSTNAME}\\\\";` if you want outout

> beneficiaryFirstName: \\YourName\\

As mentioned by the OP, you can use this to get the required output.

```
string temp = @$"beneficiaryFirstName: \\\{FIRSTNAME}\\\";
```

Comment: I need the backslashes in the string through. I need the escape characters to be ignored.

Comment: Can you please mention in the question, what is the expected  output

Comment: @viveknuna The expected output is given at the top of the question.

Comment: @CallumSmith Please check the updated answer